# I have dropdown Boolean select box in Thymeleaf and 3 options. True False and null. Getting e

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a dropdown form with three options which is part of POST FORM. TRUE, FALSE and Something Else(Tried with null, 0, just string) are three options. Now everything works just fine when i submit the form like this.

```
  <select class="form-control" th:field="*{activated}" >
                            <option id="choose" value="null">CHOOSE_VALUE</option>
                            <option th:each="state : ${T(com.company.model.User.State).values()}" id="activated" data-th-field="*{activated}"   th:value="${state}" th:text="${state}"></option>
                        </select>
```

But when i try to post and controller catches an error like this and sends it back to the view.

```
   if(!uniqueUsername) {
        ObjectError objectError = new ObjectError("ERROR", "ERROR! Username already exists!");
        bindingResult.addError(objectError);
        logger.error(MessageFormat.format("Admin {0} could not create user {1}, because Username already exists",user.getEditor(), user));
        return "user-create";
    }
```

Then i get an error saying "null" is not an boolean value or "CHOOSE_VALUE" is not a boolean value.

What i am trying to have is three options. First one must mean nothing and you can not submit form without changing it. Then javascript will tell you to choose that form. But everytime i try to add either empty option something else like Boolean-s NULL value then i get an error. If there are any other field errors that thymeleaf itself catches like field is too short then no error page is shown.

Comment: Adding a option with <option value=" "></option> will work but at the next screen it will be automaticly set to FALSE

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select class="selectpicker" title="Choose value" th:field="*{activated}" >
                            <option th:each="state : ${T(com.company.model.User.State).values()}" id="activated" data-th-field="*{activated}"   th:value="${state}" th:text="${state}"></option>
                        </select>
```

Used this:
https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/